# What is the code for Logistic Regression and MLP

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, mlp, auto-sklearn

I am trying to use AutoSklearn with a specific list of algorithms

```
Logistic Regression
Random Forest
Gaussian NB
SVC
ADA
MLP
```

I know I can use these parameters.

```
mdl = autosklearn.classification.AutoSklearn2Classifier(
    include = {
         'classifier': ["random_forest", "gaussian_nb", "libsvm_svc", "adaboost"],
         'feature_preprocessor': ["no_preprocessing"]
    #K-Folds?
    },
    exclude=None,
```

I managed to find the code for these algorithms

```
Random Forest  ==> "random_forest"
Gaussian NB  ==> "gaussian_nb"
SVC  ==> "libsvm_svc"
ADA  ==> "adaboost"
```

but could not find the codes for

```
Logistic Regression
MLP
```

can anyone tell me what are these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/manual.html#restricting-the-searchspace) states that the strings used to identify estimators and preprocessors are the filenames without `.py`.

You can find [here](https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/tree/master/autosklearn/pipeline/components/classification) the `model_id` you are looking for here.

From the documentation MLP code is `mlp`, and Logistic Regression is not implemented. (see this [issue](https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/328) for further information)

Therefore you should do as follows:

```
mdl = autosklearn.classification.AutoSklearn2Classifier(
    include = {
         'classifier': ["random_forest", "gaussian_nb", "libsvm_svc", "adaboost", 'mlp'],
         'feature_preprocessor': ["no_preprocessing"]
    },
    exclude=None
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Antoine, Do you know how can I specify the HyperParameters in AutoSklearn? I want to specify random_forst with Estimator = 1000 only or MLP with HiddenLayerSize = 100 only.. any idea how to do that?